# Background Image of a div that is responsive in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make the background image of my header div like the background image of Mr. Bill Gates in  http://www.gatesnotes.com/About-Bill-Gates/Summer-Books-2015

The header background image of Mr. Bill Gates didn't change its height even the screen is small.

I tried background-size:cover but still the height is changed when the screen is small.

I place the background-size:cover to the custom.css in my bootstrap folders.

Comment: What other code have you tried? Have you used a fixed, pixel-based height?

Comment: yes. and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Check this DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/w8f0mkbg/1/

#### HTML

```
<div id="image">
    <img src="http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/nature-wallpaper-362.jpeg">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#image img {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

#### Background Image Centered Responsive Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/905pc2p0/

*There are still lots of ways too, you can try out and see with some of them;

**CSS Tricks:** https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

**Smashing:** http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/

Comment: by the way.. how can i make it centered? like in the link sample. when the screen is become smaller, the background image focus on the center.

Answer (score 0):

The site in question uses a hardcoded height value with a fluid width:

`width: 100%; height: 564px;`

Doing similar with an inline style tag, as they do, or external stylesheet should solve your issue.